# Can't get the MiKTeX installer to work on a Windows 7 Home Premium system

Tags: installing

I've got a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium and when I try to install MiKTeX on it the installer freezes at a certain point and won't go any further. Does anyone know how I can figure out why that would be?

Comment: Is it with the Basic Installer? Maybe a corrupted download, or a firewall problem? Are there any messages?

Comment: No it just freezes.

Comment: Maybe de-activate your firewall and  download again.

Comment: do you have admin rights?

Comment: Yes, but turning off Windows Firewall didn't fix the problem.

Comment: My friend said I should uninstall MikTex then re-install it. First uninstaller froze, then he said I should recover the folders from the Recycle Bin. I did that, now the uninstaller crashes.